# Maintain active links with Tampermonkey designMode on?

Tags: javascript, web, tampermonkey

I created a script at Tampermonkey, where I can change any website.

This is my script:

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         Edit any Website
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match      *://*/*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    'use strict';
    // javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'true' ;
    document.designMode='on' ;
    void 0
})();
```

But my problem is, when I click on hyperlinks/links, nothing happens, but the input field appears (which is actually the point of this script), but I want the input field to appear only when I don’t click on links (so it should be normal to open the links I click on). Is that possible and can someone help me how to adjust it?

Comment: @zitzennuggler is it possible to use this button: ->| not to put some spaces, instead i want to use it to switch between different buttons. I hope you know what I mean?

Comment: i have no idea what you mean :) haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U already tried something like this?

```js
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         Edit any Website
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match      *://*/*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function () {
    'use strict';
    // javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'true' ;
    document.designMode = 'on';

    document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((a) => {
        a.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            location = e.currentTarget.href;
        })
    })
})();
```